# How to get the average of the number of actions per day

Tags: sql, presto

I have written the sql query:

```
SELECT id
       date_diff("day", create_date, date) as day
       action_type
FROM "my_database"
```

It brings this:

```
id     day      action_type
1       0        upload     
1       0        upload 
1       0        upload 
1       1        upload 
1       1        upload 
2       0        upload 
2       0        upload 
2       1        upload
```

How to change my query to get table with unique days in column day and average number "upload" action_type among all id's. So desired result must look like this:

```
day     avg_num_action
0        2.5 
1        1.5
```

It is 2.5, because (3+2)/2 (3 uploads of id:1 and 2 uploads for id:2). same for 1.5

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL or Presto? Which is the DBMS you are using?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner presto. but im interested in main idea

Comment: I've changed the title to describe what you want. And you see by describing the problem you come closer to the solution. "get the average of the number of actions": get the number of actions, then get their average. Two steps that I am showing in my answer.

Comment: And as Rahul Biswas shows in his answer: you can also describe the problem differently. Instead of your description 3 + 2 (the numbers of actions per ID for the day), you can just say 5 (the number of actions for the day). Thus you come to another, in this case shorter and better, solution.

Comment: comma missing after column name in select statement in given query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** I think my two-steps approach is more complicated than needed. Rahul Biswas shows how this can be done in one step. I suggest you use and accept his answer.

---

**Original answer:**

Two steps:

1. Count entries per ID and day
2. Take the average count per day

The query:

```
with rows as (select id, date_diff('day', create_date, date) as day from mytable)
, per_id_and_day as (select id, day, count(*) as cnt from rows group by id, day)
select day, avg(cnt)
from per_id_and_day
group by day
order by day;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Consider your given query as a table. If any WHERE condition needed then please enable this other wise disable where clause.

```
SELECT t.day
     , COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) avg_num_action
FROM (SELECT id,
            date_diff("day", create_date, date) as day,
            action_type
      FROM "my_database") t
WHERE t.action_type = 'upload'
GROUP BY t.day
```

Create a table from your given result set and write query based on that.

```
SELECT t.tday
     , COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) avg_num_action
FROM my_database t
GROUP BY t.tday
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=871935ea2b919c4e24eb83fcbce78973

Comment: it gives error : mismatched input '*'

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: please check this answer and let me know if any query regard this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for this logic:

```
SELECT date_diff("day", create_date, date) as day,
       COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM "my_database"
GROUP BY date_diff("day", create_date, date)
```